# Is it better to save my Reckoning for a particular situation?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Right now whenever I fill my Reckoning meter, I generally try to save it for one of two situations:

- Many enemies are surrounding me (say, 4 or more) because I believe using it can grant me a significant experience bonus and a chance for rare alchemical elements per-kill.
- I'm in a really tough fight with a strong enemy, in which case I can make use of its damage output increases.

I'm always torn about these situations.  I don't really understand the core mechanic fully - is the XP boost worth using on multiple enemies?  How much extra damage will I do, and does that really matter in a tough fight?  Are there some specific instances that really make Reckoning mode shine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hrrmm I find it works best when my ass is being kicked :)

It greatly increases your damage (I'd say by at least double) and slows down time. When you "kill" people while in that mode, they stick around and your finishing strike will kill all enemies that are down and provide you an experience multiplier based on how many enemies are down. The tutorial told me that if I don't strike the finishing blow, the downed enemies will get back up, however I haven't actually witnessed that yet.

But that said, it fills up quickly so I just use it anytime there are 3+ enemies on the screen. It provides a multiplier for the number of enemies you kill with it, so more enemies = more experience. I'd rather use it on a group of 4 small enemies than 1 big enemy.

Comment: Just to add - I have witnessed the enemies getting back up if you don't use it. It's not fun considering  they regain a bit of their health. If you used it in a large group, they will all swarm you at once. The lesson: use it, even if you still have enemies standing to at least kill the downed ones before time runs out.

Comment: I learned that the hard way as well. Finishing a pack of 8 or so kobolds that I purposely lured together to use reckoning on. Then got stuck in a wall while trying to reach the last guy, had them all get up and try to murder me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I use reckoning mode under the circumstance of many enemies and an orange.  I always add an exp potion and I typically use a precision and force potion to maximize the amount of damage to ensure I complete it in a timely manner.  I always use on a boss no matter what as a lot of times the moment you kill the boss you will gain the exp for the quest as well which gets the reckoning exp bonus and potion bonus. So the following is the best way to sum it up:

The "Thresh" monsters are typically surrounded by 3 or 4 "Boggarts".  If the thresh is red and the boggarts are yellow then you can gain quite a bit here.  Start the force, precision, magic amplification (if you want), and the exp bonus potion.  Execute reckoning mode.  Kill everything and use reckoning on the thresh.  You can gain as much as 5k of exp if it works out just right at 100% bonus.

Sometimes, you are lucky and find four or even more "Jottun" around.  I also will use the same strategy as above and gain over 8k pretty easily with at least 4 jottun if they are yellow.  Same strategy for "Ettin" as well given that some even have the orange Ettin Preist which has popped me to 8k.

As far as a boss is concerned.  The only one I can recall exactly is the story quest near the city of Canneroc.  You will meet with your fateweaver pal (as you can see I am terrible with names in games).  When you get to the boss, execute the above strategy and kill everything and then perform reckoning on the boss.  I took home 29k of exp because of this.  There were a few other moments in which I got about 30k with this strategy but it is kind of a blur as to which times this was.  A lot of side quest bosses are an easy 10 to 15k with this strategy.